# Class disabled not working <li> tag

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, disable-link

i write a class disabled in li tag show disabled style but click the menu is run

```
<li class=" disabled"> <a class="ajax-link" href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i><span> List Services</span></a></li>
```

why the menu inactive in class disable any way to disable the menu in this condition ,please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Setting an arbitrary class name to an element doesn't make it unclickable, please show the relevant CSS. And please, clean up the PHP mess from the example, this is a client-side problem.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643505/how-can-i-disable-a-specific-li-element-inside-a-ul

Comment: @jayadeeprajput  tkz it's working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS:

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events:none; //This makes it not clickable
    opacity:0.6;         //This grays it out to look disabled
}
```

add this to solve that issue !!!

Answer (score 2):

The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value.

Use this code:

```
.disabled a {
   pointer-events:none; 
   opacity:0.6;
}
```