# How to disable click and selection in li in css

Tags: css

Can anybody tell How to disable click and selection in li in css

I have tried

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events:none; 
    opacity:0.6; 
    cursor:not-allowed; 

}
```

but pointer is coming and able to select text  how to avoid

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide minimal example?

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643505/how-can-i-disable-a-specific-li-element-inside-a-ul

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `cursor` and `user-select` properties as `none`.

```
 .disabled {
    pointer-events:none; 
    opacity:0.6; 
    cursor:none; 
    -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
    -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
    -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: none;
}
```

Here is a more in-depth look at `user-select`: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/